# How can I package by maven but skip generating war file

Tags: java, maven, war

The packaging of pom.xml is `war` but I need the compiled `webapp` folder (with html/css/js/jsp, resources, classes and lib) only, because I will do some modification and package this folder programmatically and packaging this folder into war by maven waste time.

Can I skip generating war file by `mvn clean package`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want skip generating war file you can use [war:exploded plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html)

after that, you can run `mvn clean compile war:exploded`

Comment: must run `mvn clean compile war:exploded`. Without `compile`, no class files can be found under `WEB-INF/classes` folder.